# HTACCESS - Re-write URL while re-directing to a different URL

Tags: .htaccess

Lets say I have a site that has one page that handles all requests (index.php)

Now, I want tidy URL's, so I can use .htaccess to redirect to valid URL's -

**part 1** - re-directing all requests to index page where the url string is "exploded" into an array for parsing:

```
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots|files|blog|[0-9]+$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

**part 2** - `http://example.com/123456`:

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)$ index.php?user=$1 [L]
```

**part 3** - `http://example.com/blog/blog_title.html`:

```
RewriteRule ^blog/([a-z0-9-_]+)\.html$ index.php?blog=$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^blog/. /blog/ [R]
```

Obviously here, I am redirecting the blog post to index.php with the blog variable being the part before ".html" (blog_title), along with any non-compliant URL's being forwarded to the /blog/ directory.

The problem I have is that I need to then re-direct the URL to "index.php?page=blog" while keeping the address bar displaying `http://example.com/blog/`

any help would be appreciated!

Comment: What is `RewriteRule ^blog/(.) /blog/ [R]` supposed to do? Also why, when you are making clean urls, would you want your blog urls to end with `.html`?

Comment: Since it comes after the `RewriteRule ^blog/([a-z0-9-_]+)\.html$ index.php?blog=$1 [L]` line, `RewriteRule ^blog/(.) /blog/ [R]` checks to see if the directory is still set to `blog/` (not `index.php`...) and if it is, it then checks if there is anything after `blog/` then redirects the page to the `blog/` directory if needed (Rather than display a 404 page).

Also ending in `.html` gives the impression of a static page which I read somewhere is better for search engines who might have problems with a page having no file extension and treat it as a directory.

Comment: I suppose it could be `RewriteRule ^blog/. /blog/ [R]` as opposed to having the brackets, since I am not using the string after `blog/`

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. Makes sense to do that. I've never heard of search engines, not liking pages without file extension. It seems google is stupid enough to even index the extensions (see http://www.google.nl/search?q=html+site%3Agoogle.com), so I think google doesn't even extract the extension from the url. It just uses the url and doesn't care if it is a directory, file, php-script, or rewritten url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you found the solution yourself, I thought you might be interested in an alternative way to solve this. This is where I came up with :-)

```
RewriteCond $1 !^blog/.
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots|files|[0-9]+$)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?page=$1 [L]
```

Maybe you could even combine the two conditions into `RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php|robots|files|blog/.|[0-9]+$)`, but I not sure about the priority of the logical-or (i.e. `|`).

Comment: The problem would be that I would need to still use the `blog/.` section to do the actual change over / forwarding, and the selector for the `.html`

Comment: In fact, I do do the `blog` part in the initial `RewriteCond` to stop the initial forwarding!

Comment: if the urls starts with `/blog/*` it will not rewrite it, but your third rule will. This solution was only an change in your part 1, so you still need part 2 and 3. This so you don't need the extra rule you found out, solved the problem.

Comment: Ahh I see! +1 for improving method

Answer (score 0):

I feel stupid...

just added a line at the end!

```
RewriteRule ^blog/ index.php?page=blog [L]
```